# Deleted status in ListSubscriber records

Tags: marketing-cloud

According to my reading of https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscribers1/, deleting a user from a list should result in that user's status on the list as "Deleted":

> A subscriber who meets either of the following criteria has a status of Deleted:
>
> - A user has deleted a subscriber from a list other than the All Subscribers list. In this case, the subscriber's status for that list only is Deleted.
> - ...

However, if I remove a subscriber from a list using the Marketing Cloud webapp, that subscriber doesn't show up in subsequent [ListSubscriber retrievals](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_subscribers_on_a_list/)

Is this the expected behavior? If yes, is there any way I could retrieve list removals using the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular API call filters out soft deletes like this, so yes, it's the expected behavior. There currently is no way to track list changes like this through the API.